# Hiding $_GET variables by a re-direct

Tags: php, security, redirect, get

I'm using a 3rd party app that I need to integrate with my own app.  In the 3rd party app, information is posted via a form and then re-directed to my site for further processing.  The re-direct to my site will contain variables that I'll need from the form within the re-direct URL.  However, I don't want the user who published the form to be able to view those variables.

If the re-direct link is hidden on the 3rd party app (i.e. it's not in the form), then one method that I thought which *could* work would be to direct the 3rd party app to a "pre-processing" script which does the following:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['some_variable_to_save'] = $_GET['some_variable_to_save']; //properly sanitized!!
header('Location: where_i_really_want_to_process.php');
exit;
```

Then, in where_i_really_want_to_process.php I can process the session variables. Is this a secure method to ensure that the user never sees the $_GET variables?

Comment: If you want to pass the variables to another page without a user viewing them, you should use `POST`, not `GET` (although this is still not foolproof). If they kill the script or their internet goes out between pages they they'll see the data.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over this as the 3rd part app is sending the URL to me with _GET variables.

Comment: Could you instead use `cURL` and execute it in-script so that there are no redirects?

Comment: try ajax for passing data using get

Comment: I don't have control over how the data is being sent to my app; it's a "webhook" after a purchase is made.  I'm not quite sure how I would then use ajax in this situation.

Comment: @Ben Can you elaborate a bit?  (I'm familiar with cURL but am not quite sure what you're suggesting...)

Comment: If you don't have control over the 3rd party application, this could be a feasible solution though not ideal. Can you not work with the 3rd party to see if they can POST you information instead?

Comment: My guess is that as their own product develops they'll move to something more "secure" such as a POST but they're not quite there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion of using `$_SESSION` seems to be the only solution.

However to make life a little easier and to cope with any changes that may occur just put the whole `$_GET` array onto a Session variable

```
session_start();

// dont sanitization here, do it in the where_i_really_want_to_process.php

$_SESSION['previous_GET'] = $_GET;

header('Location: where_i_really_want_to_process.php');
exit;
```

Comment: It sounds like this is the way to go until their own process matures.  I'll add your suggestion of putting the entire array in my session for future-proofing.

Comment: +1 for exit (though I personally prefer die();). I'd actually suggest not sanitizing here if possible, as that keeps this file in the needs-edit-on-spec-change list. A warning, though, you can use this to shove arbitrary data into the session variable. Of course, it's limited by the URL spec to under 2,083 characters, and you'd be overwriting it every time, so that's not that bad of a space hog.

Comment: @abluejelly I tend to agree on the _not doing the sanitizing here bit_ __do it in where_i_really_want_to_process.php__.  As it makes it more difficult to do any error processing and still keep the user informed of the situation while keeping the querystring nearly invisible

Comment: Er right. "If Possible" means it's totally okay for the contents of $_GET to be stored somewhere in plaintext for an extended period of time. Obviously if it contains something like plaintext SSNs (heaven forbid), you're going to have to do some "cleaning". Though honestly I'd drop that third party in that situation and mark them as a biohazzard not to be touched with shorter than a hundred-foot pole.

Comment: usage of session is already given in the question. he needs a new solution.

Comment: @VigneswaranS I dont think there is a new solution based on the limitiations he mentions in his question.

Answer (score 1):

**It is physically impossible to "ensure" the user never "sees" some form of the data being passed if you have to have the user forward the data to you.** They must see some form of the data, otherwise they can't turn around and tell your server what the data was.

If you could encrypt the data, that would effectively hide the data from the user (assuming you use good encryption). But you lack control of the third party, so this may not be viable.

Another option would be to find a third party you can trust to give limited db access, and have them contact your server directly instead of using the client as a middleman. Without knowing exactly what you're doing, I have no idea if this is viable.

If all you're doing is trying to protect "normies" from bookmarking the GET values, the shove-into-session-then-redirect trick is plenty. Only other option would be to write something js/ajax/whatever that does it client side- however that's less transparent to the user than doing it serverside, as well as depends on the user not blocking your method of hand-waving. Very very few people disable internal redirects.

I do endorse Riggs's method (shove all of $_GET into session instead of just the current key you want) over the solution in-question, however, as it lets you pretty much ignore this helper script for the life of the application.

Comment: Based on your additional thoughts, it does in fact sound like Rigg's method is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use an associative array of variables **$_POST**:

```
$_POST = $_GET;
$_GET = [];
header('Location: where_i_really_want_to_process.php');
```

Comment: Honestly surprised if this works, since the redirect generates a new request from the client that should have null for POST. If it does, it's entirely PHP being PHP and not a good practice.

Comment: That will not make the `$_POST` available in `where_i_really_want_to_process.php` It will only waste a few milli seconds before loosing everything again